# Looping async function over array with $q in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angular-promise

My goal is to take an array of image URLs (obtained from an API, their CORS headers are set) and to loop over it, fetching each image using xhr, resizing it in a canvas element and then generate another array whose entries are the data for the resized images. My problem is that only the last entry in the array is processed properly, and everything else is a blank image- my guess is that the $q.deferred() is being overwritten on each iteration of the loop, but I don't really know because I am new to promises and async. Also, I am writing this in AngularJS v1.25. You can view my code at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/razwyZ?editors=101. I will also post it here:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$q',
  function($scope, $q) {

    resizeImage = function(imgSrc) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      // console.log(imgSrc);
      // console.log("resizing image");
      image = new Image();
      image.src = imgSrc;
      image.onload = function() {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.height = 300;
        canvas.width = 300;

        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 300, 300);
        deferred.resolve(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
      };

      return deferred.promise;
    };

    fetchImage = function(src) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.responseType = 'blob';

      xhr.onload = function() {
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
        image = new Image();
        resizeImage(url)
          .then(function(dataUri) {
            deferred.resolve(dataUri);
          });
      };

      xhr.open('get', src);
      xhr.send();

      console.log(deferred.promise);
      return deferred.promise;
    };

    $scope.picUrls = ["https://res.cloudinary.com/mediocre/image/upload/v1415293060/od9rkw2xtdtfsfiblq6k.png", "https://res.cloudinary.com/mediocre/image/upload/v1415293108/pgnbdgx0aamspgcxzwmx.png", "https://res.cloudinary.com/mediocre/image/upload/v1415294024/z7ohumjr5vs87e1nn5fl.png", "https://res.cloudinary.com/mediocre/image/upload/v1422407613/mzuce3ooqpcewddq9iih.png"];
    $scope.picArray = [];

    for (i = 0; i < $scope.picUrls.length; i++) {
      console.log("executing loop")
      $scope.picArray.push(fetchImage($scope.picUrls[i]));
    }

    $q.all($scope.picArray).then(function(imgArray) {
      console.log("executing q.all statement");
      $scope.picArray = imgArray;
      console.log($scope.picArray);
    });

  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="pic in picArray">
      <img src="pic">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually did the promises with deferred correctly. I don't know why you used a `$q.defer()` and `xhr` when you could have just used `$http.get` which returns a promise already.

You have two minor issues though:

1) you should use `ng-src` and not `src`, and the expression should be in the curly braces. Without `ng-src`, the browser would attempt to download from location `"/{{pic}}"`.

2) you have an error with `ng-repeat` due to array with duplicate entries. To fix, you need to add `track by` (and in general, to see better error, remove `.min` from `angular.min.js`.

```
<div ng-repeat="pic in picArray">
  <img ng-src="{{pic}}">
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

You have a few more issues.

1) In your `resizeImage` and in `fetchImage` you forgot to declare the `image` variable locally and since you haven't used `"use strict"` (a bad idea right there) you have effectively created a global `image` variable.

Change it to:

```
var image = new Image();
```

2) Don't reuse the array storing promises to then also store images. This generates failed HTTP requests to retrieve the `src` of the image.

Use a different variable:

```
$scope.pics = [];

// then in `$q.all`
$scope.pics = imgArray;
```

and `ng-repeat` over that:

```
<div ng-repeat="pic in pics track by $index">
  <img ng-src="{{pic}}">
</div>
```

[fork of your codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myMqKE)

Comment: Okay, so I fixed my typos like you said, but the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvrdaL?editors=101) still has the unexpected behavior I was talking about- only the last entry in the array is processed, and the rest are duplicate blank images. Also I don't understand why my console.log statement at the end logs a promise object- I thought that it would log the image data that I assigned in the callback.

edit: for some reason the original codepen didn't save, the one in this comment is a new one that I wrote.

Comment: @Soxad, you have other issues there. See updated answer